# Condition inside SQL in keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my query

```
$qry="select * from table where colnam in ($int1, $int2)";
```

`colname` values can be `1,4,3,2`

For example

```
if $int1=2;
```

I want to select `1, 2 and 3`

```
if $int1=3;
```

I want to select `2, 3 and 4`

Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data in table.

Answer (score 2):

Re-write query as:

```
$qry="select * from table where colnam BETWEEN $int1-- AND $int1++ ";
```

No need of $int2 at all. Just assign the values `2 or 3` in `$int1` only.

Comment: $int2++ to   $int1++ change

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$col= ($int1-1).",".($int1).",".($int1+1);

$qry="select * from table where colnam in ($col)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry="select * from table where colnam in ($int1,int1++,int1--)";
```

Answer (score 0):

inside sql query you can not write condition so 
use below code for your query,

```
if($int1 == 2){
  $int1 = 1,2,3;
}
elseif($int1 == 3){
  $int1 = 2,3,4;
}
```

and then execute query,

```
$qry="select * from table where colnam in ($int1, $int2)";
```